# Curl unable to get local issuer certificate with Filckr API in PHP

Tags: php, ssl, curl, flickr

Since Flickr API fully supports SSL, I did the steps following

1. Download .pem file from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem, rename it to curl-
   ca-bundle.crt, and copy to C:/xampp/php/ (I'm using XAMPP on Win8)
2. Add cacert location to my code

   ```
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "C:/xampp/php/curl-ca-bundle.crt");
   ```

Here's all my PHP code

```
 <?php

    $url = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/
                 ?method=flickr.people.findByUsername 
                 &api_key=38f6b424cbcaeb07967dc7732ddb3f32
                 &username=Sami';
    $ca = 'C:/xampp/php/curl-ca-bundle.crt';
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $ca); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
    ?>
```

And then I got

```
Curl error: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Please give me some suggestions or another way to solve local certificate issue
on Flickr API.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you include a couple of extra parameters in your curl call as you are fetching from an https source - namely:-

```
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1 );
```

and maybe also a useragent as I have found many api calls get blocked for not having a useragent

```
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'flickr-curl-fetcher' );
```

Also I noticed ( after properly reading your post ) that the cacert.pem should be renamed? This doesn't seem right - I use the following and it works.

```
       curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, realpath( 'c:/wwwroot/cacert.pem' ) );


        /* Full code that does return XML */


        $url = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.people.findByUsername&api_key=38f6b424cbcaeb07967dc7732ddb3f32&username=Sami';
        $ca = 'C:/xampp/php/cacert.pem';
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 ); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, realpath($ca) ); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1 );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'flickr-curl-fetcher' );

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
        }
        curl_close( $ch );
        print_r( $result );
```

Comment: Did you mean disable SSL?

Comment: No, you need to use ssl as the resource you are fetching with curl is over https.

Comment: I got, Notice: curl_setopt(): CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST no longer accepts the value 1, value 2 will be used instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\curl\index.php on line 21

Comment: you most likely have a newer version of PHP installed in that case.

Comment: What PHP version are you using?

Comment: 5.3.2 i think, but I checked on the mighty google and found that the option specified has been deprecated in libcurl ( http://www.nonstop.co.il/kb/view.php?kb=74 ) - does the code not work when the value is set to 2?

Comment: when set to curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);, it does work